# How can i change the price chart to BID instead of ASK in forex?

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way to see both BID and ASK prices on one chart? I can do this in Ninjatrader 8. However can't seem to do it on trading view. I trade the forex market. Please let me know if there is a Pine Script for this? Thanks

Majorcore

Answer (score 0):

Majorcore,

There is a setting to display on scales:
https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/display-bid-ask-labels-and-levels-19761/

But you can't extract this information for use into a script.